# How can I extract a file from a tar archive without creating the subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a compressed tar archive and I want to extract one file from deep in the archive to the current working directory.

Is there something better than `tar`, or a way to extract it without the directory components?

I'm doing something like this right now:

```
tar xfvz $file -C $destination $folder"/"$file
cd $destination"/"$folder
mv $file ../$file 
rm -r $folder
```

But I sometimes delete the wrong `$folder`.

For example, my archive is : `mytar.tar.gz`.
Inside it I have `myfolder/mysecondfolder/hello.txt`.

I want to extract `myfolder/mysecondfolder/hello.txt` as `hello.txt` in the current directory.

Comment: You know the name of the file you want to extract from the `.tar`? Am assuming you want only this file to be extracted from the archive?

Comment: I know the name of the file yes, but i may not know the folder name or the numbers of folders before i get to the file

Comment: And you want only that file without the level of folders you are parsing through? `tar` does not work that way, the inner folders upto the level in which the file is present is left back. You have to manually remove the folders later. Can  you update your archive in the question and state your exception again?

Comment: I update my question if i have well understand your last sentence, btw is it possible to extract with something else who could help me achived this ? like an apt-get dependency

Comment: As an aside, you seem to be quoting only the part that doesn't need quotes: `tar xfvz "$archive" -C "$destination" "$folder/$file"` would be much better.

Answer (score 6):

If GNU tar is available, you could use the `--strip-components` parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_to_extract=myfolder/mysecondfolder/hello.txt
depth=$(awk -F/ '{print NF-1}' <<< "$file_to_extract")
tar zxvf mytar.tar.gz --strip-components="$depth" "$file_to_extract"
```

From man tar:

> ```
> --strip-components=NUMBER
>       strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction
> ```

Source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/extracting-tar-gz-files-in-current-directory-689243/#postmenu_3368879

---

A shorter solution would be to use the `--transform` option, as suggested by Toby Speight:

```
tar zxvf mytar.tar.gz --transform='s,.*/,,' myfolder/mysecondfolder/hello.txt
```

Comment: Could you just explain me the "depth" line ? Thanks

Comment: @Kryze: The `--strip-components` parameter needs to know how many leading directories to strip, so we count the number of slashes in the file path using awk.

Comment: You can avoid having to count `/` by using `--transform='s,.*/,,'` or the like (which is also a GNU extension).

Answer (score -3):

Just give the full stored path of the file after the tarball name.

Example: suppose you want file `test.tar.gz` from `2.pdf`:

`tar -zxvf test.tar.gz 2.pdf`

Comment: It's not working, the command extract the folder too from the archive
    tar -xf 1481648808.tar.gz 1481648808/hello.txt.gpg
    ls
    1481648808  1481648808.tar.gz
The folder is extracted from my tar.gz

Comment: @Kryze: What you are asking cannot be achieved in a straight forward tar extraction, if the file you are seeking is present inside `x/y/file`, the folder `x/y` stays back.

Comment: @Kryze updated, this works now. File 2.pdf is extracted in the same directory as test.tar.gz

Comment: My file is inside the tar.gz and inside a folder, with your updated answer i get a file not found